# categorize with color and size in one ggplot legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot some data with are categorized in ggplot by size and color. For example:

```
require(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + 
  geom_point(aes(size = qsec, color = qsec)) + 
  scale_colour_gradient(limits=c(15, 23), low = "blue", high = "red")
```

How would I alter this so that both the color and size are represented in the same legend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you need to specify `guide = 'legend'` within `scale_color_gradient` (the default is `"colourbar"`). And then of course you need to use the same limits for the `color` and the `size` scales.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + 
  geom_point(aes(size = qsec, color = qsec)) + 
  scale_colour_gradient(limits=c(15, 23), low = "blue", high = "red", guide = 'legend') +
  scale_size_continuous(limits=c(15, 23))
```