# ggplot2 legend: combine discrete colors and continuous point size

Tags: r, ggplot2

There are similar posts to this, namely [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32649426/ggplot-combining-size-and-color-in-legend) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28669431/categorize-with-color-and-size-in-one-ggplot-legend), but they address instances where both point color and size are continuous. Is it possible to:

1. Combine discrete colors and continuous point size within a single legend?
2. Within that same legend, add a description to each point in place of the numerical break label?

Toy data

```
xval = as.numeric(c("2.2", "3.7","1.3"))
yval = as.numeric(c("0.3", "0.3", "0.2"))
color.group = c("blue", "red", "blue")
point.size = as.numeric(c("200", "11", "100"))
description = c("descript1", "descript2", "descript3")

df = data.frame(xval, yval, color.group, point.size, description)

ggplot(df, aes(x=xval, y=yval, size=point.size)) + 
  geom_point(color = df$color.group) +
  scale_size_continuous(limits=c(0, 200), breaks=seq(0, 200, by=50))
```

Comment: Any reason why you're not using `aes(color=color.group)` instead of `color=df$color.group`? That would create a color legend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing what you originally asked - continuous + discrete in a *single* legend - in general doesn't seem to be possible even conceptually. The only sensible thing would be to have two legends for size, with a different color for each legend.

---

Now let's consider having a single legend. Given your *"In my case, each unique combination of point size + color is associated with a description."*, it sounds like there are very few possible point sizes. In that case, you could use both scales as discrete. But I believe even that is not enough as you use different variables for size and color scales. A solution then would be to create a single factor variable with all possible combinations of `color.group` and `point.size`. In particular,

```
df <- data.frame(xval, yval, f = interaction(color.group, point.size), description)
ggplot(df, aes(x = xval, y = yval, size = f, color = f)) + 
  geom_point() + scale_color_discrete(labels = 1:3) +
  scale_size_discrete(labels = 1:3)
```

[image]

Here `1:3` are those descriptions that you want, and you may also set the colors the way you like. For instance,

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = xval, y = yval, size = f, color = f)) + 
  geom_point() + scale_size_discrete(labels = 1:3) +
  scale_color_manual(labels = 1:3, values = c("red", "blue", "green"))
```

[image]

However, we may also exploit `color.group` by using

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = xval, y = yval, size = f, color = f)) + 
  geom_point() + scale_size_discrete(labels = 1:3) +
  scale_color_manual(labels = 1:3, values = gsub("(.*)\\..*", "\\1", sort(df$f)))
```

[image]

Comment: Could you provide more detail on "you may also set the colors the way you like." Your solution would work if I could assign colors. In your code, I can modify 'geom_point()' to 'geom_point(color=color.group)' to assign colors to points *within* in the plot, but then the points in the legend are all black. Did you have something else in mind? Thanks for your input!

Comment: @HelenK., I transferred my comments to the answer; see the update.